# How would I spawn Heroku workers to divide and conquer list of keywords?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, process

My Heroku Rails app maintains a large frequently-changing list of keywords.

I want to spawn up N amount of workers that will equally divide up this list of keywords and work on them until they are restarted (I restart them every time the list of keywords changes). Once restarted, they divide up the keywords again and churn away.

**For example**: Let's say I have 1,000 keywords.

- If I spawn up 1 worker, that worker will take 1,000 keywords.
- If I spawn up 10 workers, each worker will take 100 keywords.
- If I spawn up 1,000 workers, each worker will take 1 keyword.

Workers basically just open a connection with Twitter for their set of keywords and process incoming tweets that match those keywords.

**Any ideas on how to set up the Procfile and delegate X keywords between N workers?**

---

Here's a naive/pseudo manual approach just for demonstration. However, I want to be able to spawn up an arbitrary amount of workers that will automatically split the keywords amongst themselves.

Procfile:

```
keywordstreamer0: bundle exec ruby keyword_streamer.rb 0
keywordstreamer1: bundle exec ruby keyword_streamer.rb 1
```

keyword_streamer.rb

```
streamer_id = ARGV.shift # 0 or 1

# Split all keywords into array of two groups and take the group
# that matches this worker id (so the two workers take different groups)
keywords = Keyword.all.split_into_groups_of(2)[streamer_id]

# Example work loop
TwitterStream.track(keywords).each do |incoming_tweet|
  process(incoming_tweet)
end
```

Then, in my app, when I need to restart my keyword workers:

```
["keywordstreamer0", "keywordstreamer1"].each do |streamer|
  restart(streamer)
end
```

I'd like to instead be able to spawn N amount of these workers but I'm am having trouble parceling out a solution. I'd appreciate any high-level overview suggestions!

Comment: Is there any relevance to the keywords being in groups? My answer to this will depend a lot on what `work on` actually does.

Comment: The keywords are just arbitrarily divided, not grouped in any sort of way. I suppose it's confusing, but basically I'm just using http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice on the array of keywords.

Comment: Whoops, can't edit my comment. I tried to update the question with more obvious/working pseudocode to show intent. `work_on` connects to a remote tweetstream and listens for the given keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just processing one keyword at a time, in no particular order or grouping, you could just use a queue.

Each worker simply fetches the next keyword off the queue (or perhaps the next batch of keywords, for performance), does the work, and then saves the results somewhere. You don't need to worry about partitioning the workload, since the workers will simply ask for more work when they're ready, allowing you to scale to N workers without needing each worker to know about the total size of the available workload.

There are many possible ways you can implement queues for your data. A couple of more specialized ones that I've used before are AMQP and Redis, but that's hardly an exhaustive list.

I'm going to take a guess and say that since you've got `Keyword.all` in your example code, and you're on Heroku, that you're using postgres. You can also emulate a queue in postgres without too much difficulty, although it obviously won't perform as well as a purpose-built queue.

Here's one way of doing it:

Add a `status` column to your keywords. It will have 3 values: ready, in-progress, and complete. The default value for the status column is ready.

The pseudocode for your worker would look like this:

```
loop do
  keyword = Keyword.where(:status => "ready").limit(1).first
  keyword.update_attributes!(:status => "in-progress")

  result = process(keyword)
  save_result_somewhere(result)

  keyword.update_attributes!(:status => "complete")
end
```

I've left out a bunch of implementation details like gracefully handling the queue being empty, initial setup of the queue, batching, and so on. But that's the gist of it. This should perform adequately for modest sizes of N, probably at least 10 or more workers. Beyond that you may want to consider a purpose-built queuing technology.

Once your queue is set up, every single worker is identical and autonomous. Just `heroku ps:scale worker=N` and you're done!

Comment: I was too unclear about what workers do. Basically, If I have 1,000 keywords and I spawn up 3 workers, each worker will take 333 keywords and open a long-running connection with Twitter that will stream in tweets that match those 333 keywords. Each worker then processes the tweets. I see that it was misleading saying the keywords themselves are processes, but tried to remove the Twitter details since I thought it was impertinent. But does that make sense?

Comment: In other words, if I have 1,000 keywords and I want to systematically spawn up 1 worker, 10 workers, or 1,000 workers, each worker will grab  1,000, 100, and 1 keyword each respectively. I'll edit my question to be much clearer.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. Basically, there's no state of "completion". The workers just sit there forever, stream in tweets given their set of keywords, and process tweets. However, your solution gives me an idea of still using a queue. If I programmatically add 5 workers to the queue and then `rake queue:run`, the first worker can take `total_keywords/workers_in_queue` (1000/5 = 200) and pop off the queue. The next worker will take (800/4 = 200) keywords and pop off the queue. Etc. 200 each. I'll mark your answer as best if nobody bites with another way of thinking about this.

Comment: Ah, okay, so you're using the twitter streaming API and you need each worker to subscribe to a set of keywords, and the set of keywords can change at some point. And you don't want there to be any overlap, because that would be wasteful. But you want to scale it to arbitrary numbers of workers. Interesting problem. I'll think about it.